# Deregister license for Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Is there a way to register a license for outlook?

I have a 3 pack user license but i need to reformat this computer. I'd like to re-enable the outlook license again once i finish reformatting it.

Is there a formal means of doing so? Or will the uninstaller take care of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think you have to worry about it. Worst case scenario is that amount of activations of Outlook will run out and you will have to call Microsoft to activate (which they do pretty quickly without asking much questions). I have reinstalled Office multiple times on different occasions and it never complained.